# How to use SVG as PWA icon?

Tags: svg, progressive-web-apps

When making a progressive web application (PWA), you have to create enormous amount of different sizes of its icon and declare them in a .manifest file. It seems obvious that a single SVG would solve this mess brilliantly but unfortunately I cannot do this for now.

I tried this:

1. Create 2 different SVG, set them square artboards (canvas) in Illustrator. Result: in Chrome devtools - either "Image file has incorrect size (1200x1200): must provide at least 144x144" or "Failed to load your svg". However, same svg on same url been opened in Chrome is visible perfectly!
2. Set "sizes":"any" in .manifest. Although this keyword mentions as accepted, devtools show an error.
3. Added "purpose": "maskable" or "purpose": "maskable any" or "purpose": "any".

Devtools say that my SVG (150x150) is less than minimal required (144x144) and also, I must supply at least one icon in png, svg(!!!) or wepP format.

Comment: You don’t _have to_ create ‘enormous amount of different sizes’ for the icon of a PWA. In the `manifest.webmanifest` file (also found with the JSON extension), you can put sizes like `144x144` (primary icon used by Chrome), `192x192` and `512x512` (powers of 2 are the more commonly used in icon sizes). Check [Google’s documentation](https://web.dev/add-manifest/), the [MDN’s documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) and [the W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/) on web app manifests.

Answer (score 17):

There are some rules by fact that are not mentioned in devtools.
You should format manifest exactly like this:

```
  "icons": [{
    "src": "/my/etc/pwa1/cheese_sq.svg", //inside the scope!
    "sizes": "48x48 72x72 96x96 128x128 256x256", //see the size in the devtools, not in editor. I've set up size 1200x1200 in Illustrator, but Chrome says it's 150x150. Also, "sizes":"any" not work.
    "type": "image/svg+xml", //not image/svg which is still visible in web
    "purpose": "any" //not "maskable any" as you may see there in answers.
  }]
```

There's so much bureaucracy in modern standarts, kill me please!

Comment: However, this one, properly registered svg icon, may not be showed in certain situations. Better use that zoo of png's.

Comment: OMG your app generates so much sizes. If this is considered good practice than there's something went terribly wrong in PWA ideology...

Comment: It is not PWA ideology LOL
It's just that there are so many different devices consumers use. I mean there are over 10,000 different Androids.
That is a collection of various icons I know are used by different browsers and different types of devices.

Comment: If there are so much devices, than Android OS should have strong support of SVG  and good resizing algorithms rather throwing this problems onto app developers.

Comment: I am would rather use SVG, but I am getting an error (or warning?) "Actual size of icon does not match specified size"...